# Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure. How can I fix this please?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, ant, robocopy, build.xml

Hy everyone!

In Jenkins when i try to build my job I run a batch command before `robocopy /mir pathSource pathDest` in tn Configue->Build of my job. But when he executes the command, he stops without run the build.xml. So he prints this just after the command batch before stopping :

```
16:47:25    Ended : Mon Nov 07 16:47:25 2016
16:47:25 
16:47:25 c:\jenkins_slave\workspace\********>exit 1 
16:47:25 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
16:47:26 Sending e-mail to: *********** (launcher, owner).
16:47:26 Notifying upstream projects of job completion
16:47:26 Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Is there more log output above your snippet? Seems like you missed the error message in the snippet you posted. Debug advice: can you run each of the commands in your build configuration successfully outside of Jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robocopy have different return codes and error levels which indicates the status of the copy. short version - you can exit 0. 
Long version - run the following:

```
Robocopy SOURCE DEST /e /np /R:5 /mt:64 /XD IGNORE

if errorlevel 16 echo ***FATAL ERROR*** & goto endError
if errorlevel 15 echo FAIL MISM XTRA COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 14 echo FAIL MISM XTRA & goto endError
if errorlevel 13 echo FAIL MISM COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 12 echo FAIL MISM & goto endError
if errorlevel 11 echo FAIL XTRA COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 10 echo FAIL XTRA & goto endError
if errorlevel 9 echo FAIL COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 8 echo FAIL & goto endError
if errorlevel 7 echo MISM XTRA COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 6 echo MISM XTRA & goto endError
if errorlevel 5 echo MISM COPY & goto endError
if errorlevel 4 echo MISM & goto endError
if errorlevel 3 echo XTRA COPY & goto endSuccess
if errorlevel 2 echo XTRA & goto endSuccess
if errorlevel 1 echo COPY & goto endSuccess
if errorlevel 0 echo –no change– & goto endSuccess

:endSuccess
exit 0
:endError
exit 1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Dvir669!

Comment: @Carlinto can you please mark is as the right answer?